# On upper semi-continuous function and limit superior

Tags: analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Why an upper-semicontinuous function is defined as :
$$
\forall x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n,\ \limsup_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x) \leq f(x_0)
$$
Whereas :
$$
\limsup_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x) = f(x_0) ?
$$

---

In which case could we have :
$$
\limsup_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x) < f(x_0) ?
$$
I sense a case where it exists $x_0$ s.t. $f(x_0)=+\infty$ at a point but not completly sure, someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

For instance $f(x)$ defined by
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
f(1) & = & 1 \\
f(x) & = & 0 \,\,\text{ ef }x\not=1
\end{array}$$
is upper semi-continuous at 1, and we have 
$$\limsup_{x\rightarrow 1}f(x)=0<f(1).$$

Comment: Are you sure ? the lim sup is defined like that : $\limsup_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \sup_{x\in[x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon]} f(x)$. And if we write properly the definition of limit the lim sup is 1 I guess ... (Probably I am wrong)

Comment: I've always seen limsup and liminf being defined as the limit of the sup over $[x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon]\setminus\{x_0\}$, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Real-valued_functions

Comment: ...But, I have seen 2 differents definitions of lim sup/inf. One from wikipedia that exclude the point in question (your definition), and another one that does not exclude the point (check the book of rockafellar 1970 "convex analysis" section 7 page 51 -http://www.convexoptimization.com/TOOLS/ConvexAnalysis.pdf). What do you think  ?

Comment: I've always excluded the point because I want limsup and liminf to be defined whether $f(x_0)$ exists or not. In the condition of continuity or upper semi-continuity, this never happens but I want to be able to say that $\limsup_{x\rightarrow 0}\sin(x)/x=1$ for instance.

Comment: And in the case where  $f $ is locally bounded, this is not a problem anymore  ? (((Because I am working with locally bounded functions)))

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as $f$ is defined at $x_0$ but could be a problem if $x_0$ is a limit point of the domain of definition of $f$.